# Issue with deployment on Wildfly 17.0.1.Final

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jboss, wildfly

I want to deploy an ear file that consists of submodules over wildfly 17.0.1.final.
The code gets deployed on wildfly 10.1.0.final properly but gives issue over wildfly 17.0.1.final.
I tried both with standalone.xml as well as standalone-full.xml.
While using standalone.xml for deployment,I get following error on deployment console:-

```
Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
```

And when I use standalone-full.xml on deployment console,I get following error:-

> {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.depl
>   oyment.subunit.\"MyEarFile.ear\".\"EAR-AllVersion1.0.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"EAR-AllVersion1.0.war
>   \" of deployment \"MyEarFile.ear\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make()Lorg/hibernate/validator/internal/util/logging/Log;","jbo
>   ss.deployment.subunit.\"MyEarFile.ear\".\"EARmobile-AllVersion1.0.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"EARm
>   obile-AllVersion1.0.war\" of deployment \"MyEarFile.ear\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make()Lorg/hibernate/validator/internal/util/logging/Log;"},"WF
>   LYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.MyEarFile.\"EjbDbfinder-AllVersion1.0\".ChangeBasicDataBaseData","jboss.namin
>   g.context.java.comp.MyEarFile.\"EjbDbfinder-AllVersion1.0\".MessegeConsumer",........
>   ..
>   ..
>   ..
>   ..]"]}}}

I am not getting how to resolve it.I tried removing sl4j dependency from pom but still it didn't work.I am using eclipse ide for this and just installed jboss tool for wildfly as other jboss tools were not getting installed.
So please let me know how I need to upgrade this to deploy the code and make it running.Please let me know If I need to to specify any more details for this.

Following is the Hibernate Dependency I am using :-

In DB module:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId> hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<!--In other Module:--->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Any help would be apreciable.

Comment: The failure with standalone.xml is to be expected : the ejb subsystem isn't included in this configuration file. For the standalone-full.xml error it looks like you have a conflict between hibernate versions, where your application tries to call a method that is not implemented by the hibernate version provided by wildfly. Could you edit your question to include which hibernate version your application expects?

Comment: Actually it's not hibernate-orm but hibernate-validator. Wildfly 17.0.1_Final includes its 6.0.16 version where the method in question takes a parameter ([javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/util/logging/LoggerFactory.html)), which wasn't the case with earlier versions (e.g. [5.3 javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/util/logging/LoggerFactory.html))

Comment: From there you've got two solutions : 1) (recommended) update your code or configuration to be compatible with the newer version packaged in wildfly ; 2) include the desired hibernate-validator version to your application and specify in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml to exclude the wildfly-provided hibernate-validator module so that the application will use its own version

Comment: Hi @Aaron I have edited my post to include Hibernate version I am using

Comment: The maven conf you've posted doesn't include an hibernate-validator artifact, but I'm thinking there's good chances that's a transitive dependency (one of the libs your app relies on uses and therefore depends on a specific version of hibernate-validator). If you're using an IDE it can certainly show you the whole dependency tree (in eclipse that'd be the Dependency Hierarchy tab), otherwise there's a `mvn` command that lists them IIRC, I could find it back if necessary. I think you should use that to identify the library/ies that do and consider whether it'd be reasonable to update them

Comment: Thanks @Aaron it was very helpful.I tried updating Hibernate versions and added jboss-logging.jar,hibernate-validator.jar and excluded jboss-logging.jar from hibernate-ehcache and this is how it worked for me.Thanks alot for your help and guiding me to the right way.

Comment: You're very welcome, thanks for giving me an update! It might be worth posting an answer with the specifics of the solution and how you came to find it, which you could then accept, it might help people having the same or a similar problem in the future :)

Comment: Yes sure I will post the solution

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.This is how I achieved the goal:-

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-weld</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Excluding jboss-logging from hibernate-ehcache,changing the wildfly dependencyand including hibernate-validation dependency resolved my problem.